# Supporting older versions of iOS from Xcode 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, xcode5

I want my application run from devices with iOS 6.0 to later (non-retina and retina). I am using Xcode 5 with iOS 7.0 as base SDK. I know the UI changes to support both versions. Just want to know about the projects settings , Deployment Target and Architecture settings in Build Settings section etc.

I am attaching the image of  Architecture settings in Build Settings section , I think properly configuring this part may solve my problem. Thanks in Advance for your help.

[image]

Comment: specify exact version of your XCode

Answer (score 3):

Make the deployment target as ios 6.0

Comment: Is the settings in attached image ok ?

Comment: Try clicking on your project name under PROJECT, then under Deployment Target, select 6.0 next to iOS Deployment Target.

Comment: @PaulVon , That's ok , I know that. Just want to make sure the settings in attached image is correct or not.

Comment: @Ayon.. Looks correct.. are u facing any issues with this settings?